# Can I share a source folder between two Maven modules in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I got this structure:

```
- module-a
  - pom.xml
  - src/main/java
    - some-folder-to-be-shared
    - others
- module-b
  - pom.xml
  - src/main/java
```

I'd like to include the code in folder `some-folder-to-be-shared` in both modules.

I have found out how to reach this goal in Maven's pom.xml with the [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Unfortunately, this makes IntelliJ assign that folder to module-b and pretending it doesn't exist for module-a.

From the menus and documentation, I couldn't find a way to assign that folder as source two both modules.

Is there a way I can tell IntelliJ that the folder is shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA project model doesn't support sharing the same content/source root between multiple modules.

I'd extract this folder into a separate module and make your 2 other modules depend on it.